# Resize Image PNG With transparence

Tags: php, image

I want to resize an image PNG with transparence plz help.
Here is the code :

```
function resize($width,$height) {

  $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

  imagealphablending($new_image, false);
  imagesavealpha($new_image,true);
  $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
  imagefilledrectangle($new_image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparent);

  imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
  $this->image = $new_image;
}
```

Comment: And the result is what? No image? Transparency is lost?

Comment: The result is that i lost the transparency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**UPDATED**

```
function createThumb($upfile, $dstfile, $max_width, $max_height){
       $size = getimagesize($upfile);
       $width = $size[0];
       $height = $size[1];
       $x_ratio = $max_width / $width;
       $y_ratio = $max_height / $height;
       if( ($width <= $max_width) && ($height <= $max_height)) {
               $tn_width = $width;
               $tn_height = $height;
       } elseif (($x_ratio * $height) < $max_height) {
               $tn_height = ceil($x_ratio * $height);
               $tn_width = $max_width;
       } else {
               $tn_width = ceil($y_ratio * $width);
               $tn_height = $max_height;
       }
       if($size['mime'] == "image/jpeg"){
               $src = ImageCreateFromJpeg($upfile);
               $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width, $tn_height);
               imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height,$width, $height);
               imageinterlace( $dst, true);
               ImageJpeg($dst, $dstfile, 100);
       } else if ($size['mime'] == "image/png"){
               $src = ImageCreateFrompng($upfile);

    // integer representation of the color black (rgb: 0,0,0)
    $background = imagecolorallocate($src, 0, 0, 0);
    // removing the black from the placeholder
    imagecolortransparent($src, $background);

    // turning off alpha blending (to ensure alpha channel information 
    // is preserved, rather than removed (blending with the rest of the 
    // image in the form of black))
    imagealphablending($src, false);

    // turning on alpha channel information saving (to ensure the full range 
    // of transparency is preserved)
    imagesavealpha($src, true);
               $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width, $tn_height);
               imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height,$width, $height);
               Imagepng($dst, $dstfile);

       } else {

               $src = ImageCreateFromGif($upfile);
               $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width, $tn_height);
               imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height,$width, $height);
               imagegif($dst, $dstfile);
       }
    }
```

Comment: What values are you sending to function? what message are you getting? what does mean "it's not working "?

Comment: i tried this
    $image->createThumb($src['final_file'], $src['final_file_100'], 100, 100); but i got the image without transparency ?!

Comment: let us continue our discussion in chat. i posted link above

Comment: I don't have 20 reputation to access the chat :s

Comment: OK. this one will work. Updated code. Added                `imagealphablending($src, false);imagesavealpha($src, true);`

Comment: This isn't working for me.. I checked if "$size['mime']" is "image/png" which is true. Still getting a black background instead of nice transparency using this code above.

Answer (score 0):

There a simple to use, open source library called [PHP Image Magician](http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com/). It uses GD and supports transparency

Example of basis usage:

```
$magicianObj = new imageLib('racecar.png');
$magicianObj -> resizeImage(100, 200, 'crop');
$magicianObj -> saveImage('racecar_small.png');
```